# How do you create complex character animation?

Tags: animation, rigging

Im asking for some general workflow to do some complex character activity animation, like dancing, playing basketball, etc.

Some video tutorial about with will be welcomed too.

Cheers!

Comment: Imho, usually it is better to create Actions and then use/reuse/blend them in the NLA https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/nla/introduction.html

Comment: Not about Blender, but character animation in general. Alao very broad and opinion based.

Comment: Actually i mean the general workflow in blender. Like what i should do first and the next. Whatever cross your mind is very appreciated. So please do inform me if you get some idea